# How to use SwiftUI canvas with original iPhone SE size

Tags: ios, swiftui

As of the release of the 2020 iPhone SE and Xcode 11.4.1, `.previewDevice("iPhone SE")` will show the newer iPhone SE, with a significantly larger screen.

However, the original smaller iPhone SE is still getting the latest updates, and it will continue to get the latest iOS 13 updates. So this phone model will be able to download any new apps we put on the App Store.
And the question is how can we preview our SwiftUI code with the dimension of this phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to use the `.previewLayout()`

[Here](https://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html) we can see the dimensions for the original iPhone SE is 320x568.

So we can use the previewLayout like this:

```
ASwiftUIView().previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320, height: 568))
```

Answer (score 3):

This will also work for showing the original iPhone SE:

```
.previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone SE (1st generation)"))
```